# Huge object in web application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object

I am writing web application and I have huge class that have more then 40 members, 3 types of arrays and have many methods.
This class represents a task with all task's ingrediants including pricing of task.
The problem is that I need to pass the client list of 40 first tasks therefore I pass 40 complete task items which turns to be very big and weight a lot of KB.
How can I reduce this object??..

Here is a pic of the class diagram:
http://www.imagehousing.com/image/624350

Comment: I don't believe I've ever before seen code that is crying out so loudly to be refactored... Give it what it wants!

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I would tackle before even thinking of sending anything is that you refactor that class into more manageable subcomponents.  Take for instance properties like `DeliveryNote`, `DeliveryNoteId`, `DeliveryNoteSerial` could be housed in a `Delivery` class. The same could be said for the `Group`, `Payback` and other similarly named properties.  When designing properties of a class, you need to ask yourself whether the properties are specific to the parent model, or are specific to a smaller problem domain.

Once you've refactored that class, you then need to determine **what** data the client needs.  Do they need every article of data in that class.  If not, why not produce a view class based on what the client needs and send only that.

If you don't think a partial view is appropriate for your data, you can use `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` attributes to control which parts of your model actually represent the data contract to be passed to the client. E.g.:

```
[DataContract]
public class Task
{
  [DataMember]
  public string PropertyA { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }

  public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, using these attributes I can enforce that `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` form component parts of the data contract. `PropertyC` will not be part of the contract, so will not be serialised.  This is of course dependent using the `DataContractSerializer` or a WCF-service (which uses that serialiser).

This also limits a single-data contract view of the model.

Comment: I have GroupId and GroupName. They are only two fields. I have another class called Group that include more then 8 members including GroupId and GroupName. I don't want to use Group class because it is bigger then what I need so I put GroupId and GroupName under this class. Should I create PartialGroup class or something like this only for GroupId and GroupName?

Comment: @Naor - Possibly, you need to determine what data needs to be sent to the client. I've updated my answer with info on Data Contracts. As you commented on the use of JSON on @xandy's answer, the `DataContractJsonSerializer` will conform to your data contract model when generating JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

In first glance, I think you need to reduce/simplify your class, that 40 members ain't really necessary to be direct members, e.g.:

Discount, DiscountTypeCode, DiscountTypeId, DiscountTypeSign can all becomes a class ->

```
class Discount {
    float rate;
    int typeCode, typeId;
    string sign;
}
```

Simpily group every member with same prefix to a class. This is needed not only to trim the size, but better maintenance. To reduce size, it's up to you whether you need to include those sub objects to send to the client, since it's a web application, I don't think everytime your client need everything in the object, so while you return your object, consider return just a partial of it, create that in another view model.

Comment: Assuming I am using JSON, how group fields will help me to reduce the size of the data sends to the client?

Comment: No, doesn't help. Suppose you are sending like 40Kb of *pure* information, markup may takes about 5Kbs or so; Other than dynamic compression of data, there's no MAGIC way you can reduce size of information.... BUT, you can, and you should control what to send to the client, as I (and others) mentioned in the answer; Client would not need everything, just give them what they need, by portion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have you to follow some basic rule. 
Having big class create problem to understand the code and maintain it.

1. List down all the nouns and Verbs
2. Group common nouns and related verbs and create a class
3. Repeat same procedure untill there is no noun and verbs remain.
4. Now you to give serious thought to created classes and their methods
      a. Findout Generic and Specialise Classes 
      b. If there is need of design pattern then think about and create relationship like
         Generalisation and Specialisation, Association, Dependency and realization

The above step will automatic give better shape to classe.